# What part of speech is 'enough' in '[Subject] is enough.'?

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, parts-of-speech, determiners

All the dictionaries I know of classify 'enough' in 'Something is enough.' as a pronoun, not an adjective.

Dictionaries such as [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/enough), [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/enough_2) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/enough) classify it as a pronoun. Even this [M-W Learner's Dictionary](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/enough), which does have an adjective category for 'enough' (instead of a determiner category), classifies 'enough' in 'That's enough, young lady!' as a pronoun.

All these dictionaries follow traditional grammar in their POS categorization. The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Pullum isn't clear about this issue, but I think it'd classify 'enough' in 'Something is enough.' as a determinative in the fused determiner-head construction, as it would classify most other "pronouns" in traditional grammar.

What's the reason for classifying this 'enough' as a pronoun in traditional grammar and as a fused determiner-head in CGEL, instead of classifying it as a good old adjective?

---

EDIT

According to @TinfoilHat, OED seems to be classifying this 'enough' as an adjective. If this is the case, why does OED depart from all the other dictionaries and CGEL?

Comment: *Enough*, like *sufficient*, **is** a good old adjective when it's a subject complement—like this: *His income is enough for his needs.* Swap in *sufficient* to test. Then try that with all the uses of *enough* as a pronoun and I think you'll see the difference.

Comment: @TinfoilHat In many dictionaries as well as CGEL, the _sufficient_ swapping test doesn't necessarily tell you that _enough_ is an adjective, because _sufficient_ can be a determiner as well as an adjective. More importantly, no dictionary I know of would classify _enough_ in your examples as an adjective. They would all classify it as a pronoun.

Comment: @TinfoilHat And more likely than not, CGEL wouldn't classify _enough_ in your examples as an adjective, either. So you're saying essentially that all the dictionaries and CGEL are wrong, are you?

Comment: From the OED: **enough**, _adj._ (and _n._) and _adv._  **A.** _adj._ (and _n._) Sufficient in quantity or number.  **2.** predicatively. 1855   MACAULAY Hist. Eng. III. 213:   It was enough for him that those bills seemed, etc. . . . That said, it's unclear if the OED is allowing a noun interpretation at this definition.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Does that mean that OED, to which I don't have access, classifies 'enough' as an adjective in 'Something is enough'? If so, that's a mystery because both LEXICO (Oxford Online) and Oxford Leaner's Dictionaries classify it as a pronoun.

Comment: Yes. Note that dictionaries are notoriously wrong, incomplete, or in disagreement when it comes to parts of speech. Also note that Lexico/Oxford is a descriptive lexicon focusing on usage, so its angle is a bit different than that of other dictionaries. Lastly note that the various grammars themselves do not agree on *enough*. You're just going to have to pick your favorite grammar and carry on with its terminology and analysis. I'm going to go with "pronoun" for the subject complement position after all.

Comment: @TinfoilHat In general, yes, dictionaries are in disagreement when it comes to parts of speech. In the particular case of 'enough', all dictionaries classify it as a pronoun, perhaps except OED (if you're right about that). So it's OED vs. all the other dictionaries. Moreover, CGEL doesn't seem to classify it as an adjective either, so it's likely that CGEL classifies it as a determiner-head, which corresponds to a pronoun in traditional grammar.

Comment: Enough of your advice; we know how to go about. (Pronoun).  
We have got enough advice (pieces of advice) (Adj).  
Enough is enough (Noun/Pron/Adj and adj/Pron/complement respectively).  
You have done enough for me. (Adv.).  
He is rich enough to think of a marriage.  (Adj. qualifying an adj.).  
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/enough_3
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/enough

Comment: Dictionaries are not authoritative on parts of speech. That's a grammatical distinction, and you go to a grammar to find out what they are. As it happens, _enough_ is a Quantifier, used in the example sentence as a predicate, short for _enough (quantity (of whatever the subject is))_. Quantifiers had not yet been discovered when The Eight Parts Of Speech were codified by the Romans (but then, neither had Adjectives). However, they're there and they have their own grammar -- they have to go before all the adjectives in a noun phrase, for instance.